# Deploy Zend to a Subdirectory

Tags: apache, zend-framework

I just started learning Zend. I managed to get the basic working (using `zf create project`) in my local web server. Let's just say my project is called **square**

The only .htaccess that I have: **square/public/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

**httpd.conf**

```
DocumentRoot "/home/amree/web"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/amree/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost square
<VirtualHost square>
    DocumentRoot "/home/amree/web/square/public"
    ServerName square
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1               square
```

I'm running my application on Linux.

From what I've gathered, I can open (loaded without any problems) the site using:

- http://square/
- http://square/default/index/index
- http://192.168.1.10/square/public/
- http://192.168.1.10/square/public/default/index/index

But I can't open it using:

- http://square/square/public (An error occurred message from Zend)
- http://192.168.1.10/square/ (got a directory listing)

I also have other web applications in the same web server. For example, the **meh** application can be opened using http://192.168.1.10/meh/ but cannot be opened using http://square/meh

My question is, **how can I load my Zend application without getting problems to other applications in the same server?** At the moment, I prefer accessing it using my local IP (192.168.1.10). It should be possible to open it from another computer in the same network.

So, in the end I should be able to load the Zend project using

1. http://192.168.1.10/square
2. http://192.168.1.10/square/public
3. http://192.168.1.10/square/public/default/index/index

And I can also open my other **meh** application using http://192.168.1.10/meh

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** indeed access your application using

- http://square/square/public

  - Using the `square` domain will match your vhost and `/square/public` will be rewritten to Zend, whom will try to run `Square_PublicController::indexAction()`
- http://192.168.1.10/square/ (got a directory listing)

  - you got a directoy listing (allowed by `Options Indexes` in `<Directory "/home/amree/web">`) because your .htaccess is located in `http://192.168.1.10/square/public`

You have to make a choice between:

- http://192.168.1.10/square
- http://192.168.1.10/square/public

---

Or maybe try an `Alias` in Apache

```
Alias /square /square/public
```